# Venues Search Foursquare API out of radius

Tags: javascript, fetch, foursquare

I'm trying to using the Foursquare Venue Search API to get the nearest places in a radius of 100 meters. I had read the documentation and test several values and parameters with no luck.

Even if I defined a radius of 100 meteres, I'm getting values 2km away from the location.

The code I'm using is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&v=20180323&limit=50&intent=browser&ll=19.2993657,-99.10689239999999&radius=100&llAcc=5186'


fetch(url)
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json()
  })
  .then(function(myJson) {
   console.log(myJson);
  });
</script>
```

Is kind of weird that the distance of the responses says venues are <100 meters away.

Hope something can help :-)

Comment: How about removing `limit=50` ?

Comment: Same thing. I see the same places than before. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

the doc says that if you set the radius parameter you have to use at least one cateroryId parameter in your query :

from 4square doc :

Limit results to venues within this many meters of the specified location. Defaults to a city-wide area. Only valid for requests that use categoryId or query. The maximum supported radius is currently 100,000 meters.